# Highlight all numbers in column B with duplicates that are in column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I use old Excel 2007 and have two columns. Column A contains 250 unique values. Column B contains 1000 values where some are duplicates.

If a value in column A is in column B, I want to highlight/color the value in column B.

I have tested conditional formatting and searched for duplicates but since column B contains duplicates, they are also selected even though they are not in column A. I can't use a formula `if A1 = B1` and so on because the same value is probably not on the same row.

Example table

```
A      B
111    323
2222   111
333    111
444    2222
       777
       888
       888
```

I want to highlight 111 and 2222 in column B above.

Comment: `if A1 = B1` would compare value of cell A1 to value of cell B1 only, as those are what you defined. It's impossible to determine why your other tests haven't been successful. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679901/edit) your question and add 1) the formula you've used 2) screenshot of the expected output and 3) screenshot of the actual output.

Answer (score 2):

Using a conditional formatting with a COUNTIF formula like in the screen cap below might be what you are looking for. (COUNTIF(A:A,B1)

[image]

If not hopefully it gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A:$A,1,FALSE)))
```

[image]

Comment: Tested this out and works as what OP wanted.